# div above absolute div and overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a setup where I have an absolute div that is set to left position and right position to allow for liquid layout. This all works nicely but then I run into an issue where I have a div below that with some copy. The issue is that div with the copy should be below the absolute positioned div. Right now its showing up above it which is not correct.

I have often seen this issue because of collapsing parent div's after the child have been set to absolute, but to get around that I use clear all or overflow:hidden on the parent and it stops that collapse from happening. This time around its not collapsing but its showing my bottom div above the top div.

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cNf7/2/) link to show you my code.

Comment: In your fiddle you have some nonmatching tags. Can you go back in and correct that? It may be the cause of your problems. Note the red divs at bottom. The tidyup button should help you too.

Comment: That was a missing a tag but that wasn't the problem. Sorry about that. Still having the other issue.

Comment: `clear` is used to clear floats, not absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: kingjiv  I'm very aware of that but I'm not using absolute positioning to clear floats. Unless you are seeing that somewhere in my code, Or i'm missing something you are seeing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think this will work. You have the container `footer`. This contains two child divs - `footerWrapper` and `footerTerms`.

FooterWrapper is absolutely positioned. So it is taken out of the flow of all other elements. footerTerms is a sibling of footerWrapper and naturally starts in the top left of its parent, footer.

why is footerWrapper absolutely positioned when it seems you want it to affect the content flow of your page? Make it relative or leave it static.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/7cNf7/3/

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footerWrapper"> 
    </div>
    <div class="footerTerms">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: footerTerms is not a sibling of FooterWrapper. Its outside of  FooterWrapper. FooterWrapper is absolute position so I can set a left position on it and also have a right position on it. Right now left is set to 0 but this will change.

Comment: I guess you have a point about the relative positioning I can always set the left and right positions of a relative div.

Comment: take a look at your code again. footerTerms is indeed a sibling. I updated my answer with all the stuff in the middle deleted so that you can see.

Comment: Actually that doesn't work because the relative position if set to left 200px now pushes everything outside the outter frame

Comment: mrtsherman, I just checked my code and  footerTerms is a child of footer not of footerWrapper. footerWrapper is set to absolute. But then below that div outside of footerWrapper is footerTerms and this is where the issue is. I need footerWrapper to be set to absolute so I can control the position on both left and right of the page and also keep it within window boundaries. I updated your fiddle to show why position relative would not work. See .footer .footerWrapper class where I set the left to 200px. It now positions the div outside the window which is not good  http://jsfiddle.net/7cNf7/4/

Answer (score 0):

I have probabaly mis-understood what you want to do, but if you wanted a liquid layout why not use something like this:

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #footerWrapper {
        background: #ccc;
    }
    #footerWrapper .section {
        float: left;
        width: 33%;
    }
    .clear:after {
        content: " ";
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        visibility: hidden;
        line-height: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
    html[xmlns] .clear {
        display: block;
    }
    * html .clear {
        height: 1%;
    }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footerWrapper">
    <div class="clear">
        <div class="section">
            Footer section 1<br />
            Footer section 1<br />
            Footer section 1
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            Footer section 2<br />
            Footer section 2<br />
            Footer section 2<br />
            Footer section 2
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            Footer section 3<br />
            Footer section 3<br />
            Footer section 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="terms">
        Terms
    </div>
</div>
```

Then if you wanted to hook the footer to the right of the page for example you can just edit the #footerWrapper CSS and give it a width and float.

Comment: Thanks Sour Lemon, I'm not sure I get how this relates to my structure. So section is the same as the dl elements except you chose to use a div? Then where did you pull the 33% number from, for each section? You say float all sections to the left bit then you say pin it to the right if needed. I cant give footerwarpper a width because its liwuid based I don't have pixel widths. Also how would float left help when the left side has to be a specified amount of poixels from the left, but also has to span the widht of the browser on the right and updated correctly when scaling the browser.

Comment: Yes I chose to use divs instead of dls, and the 33% was taken from doing some simple math, 100 / 3 then rounding the result down to 33, meaning that no matter how wide the footerWrapper is they would all take up an even amount of space. And if pinning the footerWrapper with a width and float to the right doesn't make sense then disregard that comment. I just thought that is what you wanted to do after looking at your code and the resulting page. The point is that my code above is a footer which can span the browser width with 3 sections taking up even space and a div below it for other text.

Comment: Thanks Sour Lemon for explaining your setup. Your setup indeed does work but it doesn't solve the issue with been able to set a specified position on the left and then pinning it to the right. Using absolute positioning allows for this. But because it takes it out of the natural flow of other elements after it, I'm now left with no way for the element below it to know where its position below it should be. It naturally wants to go above to the previous objects position which was footerWrapper before it was set to absolute. The main question is how to get around this to position footerTerms.

Comment: If you really must use absolute positioning then you will need to give the relative parent element a height and then you will probably need to make the terms container absolute too just to hook it to the bottom of the parent element. If you don't want to absolute position the terms element then you can wrap the absolute positioned stuff in yet another relative element and give that a height, which would then push the terms down. But if you want to use absolute positioning then no matter what you do you will have to specify heights somewhere. Unless of course you're open to using jQuery etc...